# MVC 6 autocomplete Free Text search single input with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two tables `Company` and `Category`. When typing in the textbox i would like to retrieve two columns from `Company` table and 1 column from `Category` table. Here is an e.g of the search parameters.

--- CategoryName Suburb State ----

Can someone please advise on how i should tackle this.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you have tried so far, so we can see you have at least tried and not want others do the work you get paid for such basic problems

Comment: @Tseng if you have clearly read the summary of this question you would know that it doesn't say anything about wanting others to do the work. BTW, yes it is a basic problem but there is so many ways achieving this. All i'm trying to do is build it in a efficient way with dramatic performance to handle 10000 + records without loosing performance.

Comment: @Tseng So all i'm asking is for other developer's advice who have experience in this field.

Comment: You still have not shown any evidence of what you have tried before asking the question. Your question reads like "I have did no research and didn't try anything to solve this problem, Can you do it for me?". Show us that you have done your home work and people may help you. And this is definitely a question that yields thousands of results on Google

Comment: @Tseng i know how to implement it in multiple ways but why would i do that  first ?? it doesn't make sense if i'm asking for advise from others of how they tackled this situation first before i implement a solution. FYI, you mentioned that people may help.... look at the below answer, it looks like there are people who actually "UNDERSTANDS" the question....

Comment: To prove that you did some research and tried to solve it in a few ways which did not work for some reason (name the reasons why it wasn't working) for your scenario. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "3. Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.": This fits closest to your question since you have not a specific problem with your implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For autocomplete purpose you can use the [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) tool, it is easy to implement.

Now to get the data while autocomplete, you can use a cache mechanism(considering you dont have bulk data to come up as autocomplete feature..) around the database. An api(GET) functionality can be useful here.

In case the user need to see something that does not appear in autocomplete, a "GetData" or "Search" functionality will be needed that actually hits the database and updates the cache to help future users.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would the performance be with your approach ? I'm estimating there would be 10000 + records.

Comment: Well, honestly I didn't think about such large number of records while suggesting this approach...but I don't see the number of records being a issue for performance...it depends on the operations taking place to pick those data...and also your server configuration...for such large data access scenarios we need POCs to know if the approach is actually feasible...